# How do I create a simple breadcrumb with pathauto?

Tags: 7, path-aliases, breadcrumbs

I'm using Pathauto to setup my url paths like this:

www.blah.com/parent1/parent2/page-name

I want my breadcrumbs to mirror this on every page:

Home >> Parent1 >> Parent2 >> Page Name

I've installed custom breadcrumbs but it wants me to create a custom breadcrumb for each content type. Can I just create one to use site wide? Preferable add via a block or view.

Comment: Both [Easy breadcrumb](https://drupal.org/project/easy_breadcrumb) and [Crumbs](https://drupal.org/project/crumbs) do this. Easy breadcrumb is more light-weight and works immediately. Crumbs has more capabilities and you need to enable the "path" plugin and disable all other plugins to get *only* the path-based breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 1):

I guess [easy_breadcrumb](https://drupal.org/project/easy_breadcrumb) module would be good to use for this scenario.

> The Easy Breadcrumb module provides a plug-and-play block to be embedded in your pages, typically at some place near the page's header. Easy Breadcrumb uses the current URL (path alias) and the current page's title to automatically extract the breadcrumb's segments and its respective links.

Example: URL like `gallery/videos/once-a-time-in-cartagena`, Easy Breadcrumb will automatically produces the breadcrumb as

> Home >> Gallery >> Videos >> Once a time in Cartagena

or

> Home >> Videos >> Once a Time in Cartagena

Again, the breadcrumb presentation will vary depending on your module's settings.

Answer (score 0):

A little digging into this topic and I found there is an alternative module that is highly rated with good support. https://www.drupal.org/project/path_breadcrumbs

> Path Breadcrumbs module helps you to create breadcrumbs for any page
>   with any selection rules and load any entity from the URL!